# Do the complex conjugate eigenvalues add up in pairs for the addition of a matrix and its transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I encountered a few matrices like the ones in the following:

$A_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0\\0 & 1 & -1\\-1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, $A_2=\begin{bmatrix}0.84 & -0.62 & -0.22\\-0.22 & 0.84 & -0.62\\-0.62 & -0.22 & 0.84\end{bmatrix}$ which respectively have eigenvalues $\lambda(A_1)=0,~1.5\pm{j*0.866}$ and $\lambda(A_2)=0,1.26\pm{j*0.3464}$.

What surprises me is $\lambda(A_1+A^T_1)=0,3,3$ and $\lambda(A_2+A^T_2)=0,2.52,2.52$, i.e. the eigenvalues of the resultant matrix are sum of corresponding complex and complex conjugate eigenvalues. Is this associated to any property of matrices which make the resultant eigenvalues of $(A_i+A^T_i)$ twice the real part of eigenvalues of $A_i$?

I have one more matrix to show similar situation.

$V=\begin{bmatrix}-0.5773 & -0.5773 & 0.5773\\-0.5773 & -0.288675 & -0.288675\\-0.5773 & -0.288675 & -0.288675\end{bmatrix}$, which gives

$\lambda(V)=0,-0.5773\pm{j*0.8164}$ and $\lambda(V+V^T)=0,-1.1547,-1.1547$.

My approach: any matrix $A=\dfrac{1}{2}(A+A^T)+\dfrac{1}{2}(A-A^T)$ and for a nonzero vector $x$, we get
 $x^T{A}x=\dfrac{1}{2}x^T(A+A^T)x$ since $x^T(A-A^T)x=0$ due to skew-symmetricity of $A-A^T$.

Therefore $x^T(A+A^T)x=2x^T{A}x=2x^T{P}DP^{-1}x$, where $A$ is decomposed as $A=PDP^{-1}$ with $D$ being a diagonal matrix with all eigenvalues of $A$ along its diagonal and $P$ is a unitary matrix with complex conjugate transpose denoted by $P^*=P^{-1}$. [The eigenvectors of $A_{1},A_2,V$ are independent and constitute a basis for $\mathbb{C}^3$].

Since $2x^T{PDP^{-1}}x\leq{2}x^T\text{tr}(PDP^{-1}){x}=2x^T\text{tr}(D){x}=4*\text{real}(\lambda)\|x\|^2$. But this does not help me prove the claim. Ant hint or references will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52578/eigenvalues-of-sum-of-a-non-symmetric-matrix-and-its-transpose-aat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the given eigenvalues, there seems to be a typo in $V$: the sign of the $(1,2)$-th entry should be positive instead of negative, i.e.
$$
V=\frac1{2\sqrt{3}}\pmatrix{
-2& 2& 2\\
-2&-1&-1\\
-2&-1&-1}.
$$
It can be easily verified that $A_1,A_2$ and $V$ are [**normal matrices**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix). Since normal matrices are unitarily diagonalisable, the said observation follows immediately because you are basically dealing with the scalar case.

Answer (score 2):

This property holds here only because all of your examples share very special properties:

1. $A$ is not invertible
2. $A+A^T$ is still not invertible (not automatic, see $A=\left(\matrix{0&0&0\\1&0&0\\1&1&0\\}\right)$)
3. Besides the eigenvalue $0$, $A+A^T$ has only one eigenvalue, say $\lambda,$ of multiplicity $2$.

Whenever all this holds, then since $2\lambda=\operatorname{Tr}(A+A^T)=2\operatorname{Tr}(A)$, you see that $\lambda$ is indeed the sum of the complex eigenvalues of $A$.

**Remark.** Any real symmetric matrix has real eigenvalues. The fact that the imaginary part disappears is nothing surprising.

**Remark 2.** There are matrices that satisfy 1. and 2. above, that have non-real eigenvalues, but which do not satisfy 3. (and hence your conclusion fails for these matrices). For instance, Take $$A=\left(\matrix{0&0&0\\0&0&-2\\0&1&0\\}\right)$$ Conditions 1. and 2. are clear. The eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ and $\pm i\sqrt2$. The eigenvalues of $A+A^T$ are $0$ and $\pm 1$.

**Remark 3.** This does not mean that you don't have discovered something. But you would need to say a bit more about how you created these matrices so that someone can derive a general proof of what is going on *in your specific settings.*